# Give the transformation matrix that send $\vec i$ on $ [1,1/2,0]$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asked to give the linear transformation that sends $\vec i$ on $[1,1/2,0]$ , $\vec j$ on $[-1/3,1,0]$ , $\vec k$ on $[1/4,1/4,1]$.

Is it a translation where I need to use the actual $i,j,k$ vectors or is it just changing the $i,j,k$ vectors to the new ones? It's in french and it says 'qui envoie $\vec i $ sur $[1,1/2,0]$'

What would be transformation matrix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the image vectors is one column of the corresponding matrix representation of the linear map.

To see this, consider the following, for coefficients $\alpha, \beta, \ldots$:

$$A(\vec i) = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \delta & \eta \\ \beta & \epsilon & \theta \\ \gamma & \zeta & \iota \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \end{bmatrix}$$

But you know the result should be

$$A(\vec i) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1/2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

(It sounds like) you want a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $$T\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{1 \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ 0}.$$
(and so on). That means you want a $3\times 3$ matrix $T= (t_{ij})$ such that for example
$$
\pmatrix{t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} \\ t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} \\ t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33}}\pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{1 \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ 0}.
$$
From this you should be able to see what the entries $t_{ij}$ are.